# Elastic Beanstalk Deployment Errno 2 No Such File / Directory

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

It's my first time deploying something to AWS using Elastic Beanstalk and so far I've gotten to the point where I can run `eb create` and get started.  The first time I did this I got `Errno 13`.  Specifically, I got to the point where it tried to create the application and then:

`Creating application version archive "app-150423_212419".
ERROR: IOError :: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './.viminfo'`

I learned that this is a root access issue and so I followed a step found [here](http://www.codeitive.com/0QxqjkXjVX/e138-cant-write-viminfo-file-homeviminfo-closed.html) that stated I should try the bash command:

`sudo chown -R test /home/test`

Here test = my user name and home = Users.

This got me to the error `ERROR: OSError :: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './.collab/ext'`

I'm really not sure what that directory is supposed to be or why it's trying to access it.  How can I choose a proper directory so that I can get things up and running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eb create` will attempt to zip up your entire directory and deploy it to an elastic beanstalk environment. I am not sure why certain files seem to not exist(maybe you have some symlinks?).

It also looks as if you might be trying to run `eb create` in your home directory. **Dont do that**. In fact remove the  `.elasticbeanstalk` folder from your home directory right now.

All you need to do is go into your project directory, run `eb init`, then `eb create`.